# Command for yum to install all packages without dependency

Tags: fedora, yum

Is there any way for `yum` to install only the specified packages, that do not have any dependencies? I'm trying to install all `python2` libraries. The code:

```
su -c 'yum install python-\*'
```

And I get (ignore that one broken package):

```
Install                        730 Packages (+257 Dependent packages)
Skipped (dependency problems)    1 Package
```

But I want install only `python2`-libraries that didn't have dependencies.

Comment: Why do you want to install packages without their dependencies? Or am I understanding wrong?

Comment: For example I want install only the Python libraries and not the software the libraries that used other software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Possible solution:**

Installing `yum-plugin-downloadonly`:

```
su -c 'yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly'
```

Downloading all `python2` and `python3` libraries (make sure `/tmp/cache` exists):

```
su -c 'yum --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp/cache install python-\* python3-\*'
```

`cd /tmp/cache` and remove all unneeded packages - `rm !(python*.rpm)`.
Finally, install all packages:

```
su -c 'yum --disablerepo=* --skip-broken install \*.rpm'
```

This will install all packages that have dependencies due to no repository available with additional packages.